# Django Admin + FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME + Login redirects incorrectly

Tags: python, django, nginx

I've got Django running behind Nginx with `fastcgi_pass`. I run Django at a subpath like `/django/sample`.

```
location /django/sample {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8025;
}
```

I use `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME` in the Django settings module, which seems to fix all the issues I was having in regards to it running at a subpath.

In settings.py:

```
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = "/django/sample/"
```

I go here to login with admin (and correctly get the admin UI):

```
http://server/django/sample/admin
```

But when I submit, it redirects to:

```
http://server/django/sample/django/sample/admin
```

What's really strange is that if I change `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME=""` the login works.

BUT, then all of the links in the admin page are `/admin`, not `/django/sample/admin/`

What the heck am I missing? Setting `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME="/django/sample/"` seems to fix everything except admin login.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

I've also tried using `fastcgi_split_path_info` in nginx conf (and take out `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME` in settings). Again, that fixes all the path issues except the admin login redirect.

conf like this:

```
location /django/sample {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/django/sample)(.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8025;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

FYI, I gave up. All the documentation says it's supposed to be easy. But it's too much of a pain to deal with. I instead am requiring our Django apps to use a subdomain and setup a vhost with the server. This way Django can run at document root "/"

Comment: I know it has been a few years later but I tell you I am having the same problem. This is #$*@$(! I make several tests in the Development server and it works perfectly, but as soon as it is transitioned to production some links start to get broken, such as Redirects. This is driving me crazy. This should have been better developed.

Comment: I gave up as well. https://serverfault.com/questions/1076763/django-gunicorn-with-nginx-reverse-proxy-wrong-redirect-to-base-path

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, I've written up a solution in another thread that's worked for me when I have a proxy server in front of a Django server using wsgi.

As I remember troubleshooting this a long time ago... you saw the out-of-sync behavior because of the way the Django admin sets up and processes the `next` param on the form submit.

Based on my experience, Django sites should definitely use `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME` to modify the way your backend generates links, and your proxy server should also strip out the subfolder (i.e. script-name) part of the path.

The other thread:

[Host Django on subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941075/host-django-on-subfolder/47945170#47945170)