# Why is staticfiles not able to find or serve .css, using FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME in docker

Tags: django, docker, django-urls, django-staticfiles

EDIT/Workaround:

I got this working.  I think there is an unfortunate interaction of `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME`, the requirement for `STATIC_URL` to end in `/`, and the behavior of `django.conf.urls.static`.  I'll mark this answered when I'm able to put together a step-by-step explanation.

Meanwhile, here's the recipe that works for me:
`urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns += static("static", document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

`settings.py`

```
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = "/the-prefix-i-need/"
STATIC_ROOT = "/static/"
STATIC_URL = "static/"
```

`STATIC_URL` has to end with "/" (or `runserver` fails).  But if `static`'s first argument ends with `/` it pulls in the `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME` into the URL pattern it is looking for, and doesn't match "/static"

---

In development (DEBUG=True) mode, running in docker on a host where the site is served with a prepended path corresponding to a branch, I am unable to get static files working.

Using python 4.0.6

In `settings.py` I have these settings:

```
DEBUG = True
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent # default generated
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = "https://pmdocker01d.pm.local:8443/bi-web-utils/ta0624/"
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

In my html file:

```
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'tableau_explorer/style.css' %}">
```

And my css is in:

`django_root/tableau_explorer/static/tableau_explorer`

On my development machine, both running manage.py from the sheel, and
in a dockerfile, it works.  In that setting, I don't have FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME.

When it is on the other docker host, the generated HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/tableau_explorer/style.css">
```

And I get a 404 error.

If I change:

`STATIC_URL = 'https://pmdocker01d.pm.local:8443/bi-web-utils/ta0624/static/'`

Then it instead of a plain 404 I get message that it's getting HTML instead of css, because the server is returning this

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://https://pmdocker01d.pm.local:8443/bi-web-utils/ta0624/static/tableau_explorer/style.css
Using the URLconf defined in bi_web.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
....
The current path, static/tableau_explorer/style.css, didn’t match any of these.
```

For the other docker host I tried adding this to the main project
urls.py (not tableau/explorer/urls.py) I tried adding this and and
couldn't see any difference:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [ . . . . ]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

If I browse to `https://pmdocker01d.pm.local:8443/bi-web-utils/ta0624/static/`

I get the error message **"Directory indexes are not allowed here."**, whereas
other urls like making it end "staticx/"  it just says page not found.  So
I think static is doing *something*, but I can't tell that anything at all is
being gathered there and don't know how to check.

If I make a shell connection into the running docker host, it seems like static
is finding what I'd expect:

```
$ python manage.py findstatic tableau_explorer/style.css
Found 'tableau_explorer/style.css' here:
  /code/tableau_explorer/static/tableau_explorer/style.css
```

Anyone know right off what's going on and can tell me "type this and it'll work?"

If not...

My question now is - what is the staticfiles supposed to be doing with files
in development mode, and how does it serve them?

- is it supposed to intercept any request that begins with "static/"
- when the app starts running, does staticfiles gather the .css files from
  different applications "static" folders,  and put copies into an on-disk
  repository I can verify, or put verbose logging on? -- Should I be able
  to see the files in a particular directory on the running server?
- is the BASE_DIR setting relevant to staticfiles?  I am using what was
  generated by `manage.py createproject`
- in staticfiles nowadays, is it supposed to take care of appending "static" into
  the urls?  I thought I shouldn't need to modify urls.py?

-- Edit:
Since posting I added `STATIC_ROOT=/static` in the settings.py file, and in Dockerfile I added collectstatic. When I shell into the running docker image on the host I see

`$ ls -l /static/tableau_explorer/style.css`

The files are present good, and are other-accessible all the way down.

The rendered HTML file has

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pmdocker01d.pm.local:8443/bi-web-utils/ta0624/static/tableau_explorer/style.css">`

and if I browse directly to that link, Django is complaining it doesn't match any path... I feel like I have to do something in urls.py to give the request to staticfiles to handle?

The response when I browse is the familiar:

```
<html lang="en"><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Page not found at /static/tableau_explorer/style.css</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="summary">
    <h1>Page not found <span>(404)</span></h1>
    <table class="meta">
      <tbody><tr>
        <th>Request Method:</th>
        <td>GET</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Request URL:</th>
        <td>http://https://pmdocker01d.pm.local:8443/bi-web-utils/ta0624/static/tableau_explorer/style.css</td>
      </tr>
      
    </tbody></table>
  </div>
  <div id="info">
    
      <p>
      Using the URLconf defined in <code>bi_web.urls</code>,
      Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
      </p>
      <ol>
. . . .  Nothing about "/static" . . .         
      </ol>
      <p>
        
          The current path, <code>static/tableau_explorer/style.css</code>,
        
        didn’t match any of these.
      </p>
    ....
```

Comment: Are you sure `DEBUG` really is `True` or some truthy value?

Comment: Yes, I know it says `DEBUG = True` in `settings.py` and I believe that last bit, where Django gives details of the urls it searched,  demonstrates the setting is in effect.

Comment: This might be relevant, from https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33293: "Anything that goes through reverse/resolve in terms of generated URLs (for Location redirects etc) should end up with the correct values."   Also do be checking out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941075, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103470.